# Python find attribue and remove parent and child

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I want to remove the specific xml element using finding the attribute.

Here is my xml file example

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>ptest</name>
  <uuid>6119613e-4ba6-4be9-a1a2-9a33ca293341</uuid>
  <description>Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS</description>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/ptest.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/iso/ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/iso/freebsd-amd64.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdd' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>
  <devices>
</domain>
```

Now I want to remove the disk block using its attribute source='/home/iso/ubuntu-12.04.3-server-amd64.iso'

Would you please help me how I can do this.

Umar

Comment: Did you try ElementTree?

Comment: What have you tried? What framework/technology are you using to traverse the XML document?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have prior knowledge on how to use XPath in python -because I don't have it-, you can try to use following XPath to get `<disk>` element described in this question :

```
//disk[source/@file='/home/iso/freebsd-amd64.iso']
```

That basically select all `<disk>` elements that has child `<source>` elements having attribute `file` value equals `'/home/iso/freebsd-amd64.iso'`.

Comment: Well its giving me an error ("expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)

Comment: quick search on google suggested me that the error is specific to python library you're using (ElementTree doesn't support attribute selector or something, I really not sure). Sorry, can't help with this matter

Comment: Well its version issue, I have checked in python 2.7 and its working there, anyway thanks

Comment: you're welcome, and well done you fixed the error! Don't forget to accept the answer. More info : [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)